# "I can deal my own disasters"

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions

A line by Meryl Streep's character Donna in the film *Mamma Mia!* grates:

> Sam: Look, I'll help. Let me have a look at this. (referring to a crack in the ground)
>
> Donna: No, that's all right, I can **deal my own disasters**. ([source: YouTube](https://youtu.be/Y9Gr2toAvBE?t=40))

Doesn't she mean to say: "I can deal *with* my own disasters"? Is the preposition omission colloquially kosher? I feel it is too obvious to be a slip-up. What does "deal" mean here then if not part of "deal with"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I listened to that clip, I could absolutely *not* hear Ms. Streep saying "with". It sounded like she said, "I c'n ... deal ....... my own disasters".

However, in American English, we don't talk about "dealing a disaster". We exclusively deal *with* disasters.

So I'm pretty sure she must have said "with", and either that word was so quiet as to be inaudible, or maybe it got accidentally dropped from the sound track recording (if that's even possible?)

But, no: "I can deal my own disasters," is not idiomatic.

Comment: Heh. Maybe her microphone was one of those ones that turns off when there's too low level sound, like on certain two-way radio coms. "That's one small step for man..."